# Implementing NavieBayes in C#

Tags: c#, data-mining

Just wondering can I implement NavieBayes algorithm in C#? I just want to calculate the precision, TP-rate, FP-rate etc using Navie Bayes algorithm in C#.

I just calculate mean and standard deviation for my dataset using SQL logic

```
SELECT state, AVG([v2o] * 1.0) FROM portability WHERE state = 'Queensland' GROUP BY state
```

and

```
SELECT state, STDEV([v2o] * 1.0) FROM portability WHERE state = 'Queensland' GROUP BY state
```

Can anyone tell me how can I implement Navie Bayes algorithm.

For instance lets consider the below dataset as example

[image]

Can anyone tell me the logic to implement Navie Bayes for the above dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Accord.net](https://code.google.com/p/accord/) library. It has an implementation of the Naive Bayes algorithm that you can use.